# Filling a string from an array with loops only gives me the last element in the index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple code. I am trying to duplicate every letter in a string. For example if we use my current username here on stackoverflow `Jos` I want to run a loop and fill an empty string with a duplicate of every letter. so I want it to be `JJooss`
However whenever I run the loop, it does not fill it all and only gives me the last index element in the string. It just gives `ss`
Here is my code:

```
char="Jos"
list_char=list(char)
new_char=""
for i in range(len(list_char)):
    new_char=list_char[i]*2

print(new_char)
```

I was wondering what I could be possibly doing wrong in the loop?

Comment: `new_char += list_char[i] * 2`

Comment: Oh I see now, I assign a new value to the string everytime in the loop, thats why it wasn't working properly, thank you and sorry for the silly mistake.

Comment: By the way, that list conversion is not necessary. strings are iterables as well...

Comment: Yes I figured, I just used the list conversion because it was something I learnt before I wrote this code

Answer (score 2):

Using string concatenation

Use the code:

```
char="Jos"
list_char=list(char)
new_char = ''
for i in range(len(list_char)):
    new_char = new_char+(list_char[i]*2)

print(new_char)
```

Output:

```
JJooss
```

Comment: Why not `new_char += list_char[i] * 2`?

Comment: Most of this code (except one line) is similar to the original. It would be much more helpful if you posted that single line or explained the change instead of having readers play "find the differences"

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: Btw `for i in range(len(...))` is an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358753/why-we-use-rangelen-in-for-loop-in-python). In many cases, including this one, `for element in list` would be suitable and cleaner.